# How to specify a STRING as a delimiter in HIVE table creation

Tags: hive, delimiter

My data looks like:

**a||b||c**

To fetch the data my create table statement is:

CREATE TABLE

( col1 STRING,

col2 STRING,

col3 STRING)

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY "||";

But here it is taking '|' as the delimiter not "||".

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: `FIELDS TERMINATED` just support `char`. So `||` is not supported. see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [RegexSerDe](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java) when dealing with multi-character delimiter strings:

```
create table mytable (
  col1 string,
  col2 string,
  col3 string
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
"input.regex" = "^([^\\|]+)\\|\\|([^\\|]+)\\|\\|([^\\|]+)$",
"output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s")
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/path/to/data';
```

Note: refine the regex to suit to your needs